# Setting user data into HTML tags using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, methods

i've been trying to call a method using javascript onclick(instead of running the code on page_load)
to get the data i want to be printed on the page in the right places (in order for the user to edit his information) but i can't figure out how to do it with a static function.
i haven't yet learned how to use non-static functions but when i removed the static part it allowed me to access my html tags, but the code ran regardless of whether i called the method or not.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" onclick="<%GetUserData();%>"/>
```

**Behind code**:
paymentOptions is the id of the select tag,
notnow is the radio for not choosing a payment option, and payment is the radio for choosing a payment option, which then shows the select tag

```
  static void GetUserData()
{
    string sqlS = "select * from UserInfo where IDD='" + Session["UserId"] + "'and Pass='" + Session["UserPass"] + "'";
    DalAccess dal = new DalAccess(sqlS);
    ds = dal.GetDataSet(sqlS);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];


        if (row["PaymentOptions"].ToString() == "NotNow")
        {
            notnow.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {

            payment.Checked = true;
            switch (row["PaymentOptions"].ToString())
            {
                case "option1": paymentOptions.SelectedIndex = 1;
                    break;
                case "option2": paymentOptions.SelectedIndex = 2;
                    break;
                case "option3": paymentOptions.SelectedIndex = 3;
                    break;
                case "option4": paymentOptions.SelectedIndex = 4;
                    break;
                case "option5": paymentOptions.SelectedIndex = 5;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**It gives me this error:**
 an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property

Obviously, i understand what this means, but my question is:
How do i access HTML tags in a static method?

Comment: Please, if anyone could help, it'll be spectacular.

Comment: Fyi your sql code is suceptible to a sql injection attack. You should use parameters not building a select atatement

Comment: @JoshBerke I'm completely aware of its vulnerabilities but that doesn't concern me as of now. What concerns me is what i asked, and only what i asked. please, do help me with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access html from a ststic method they are only available on an instance

Comment: Alright, then i'd have to choose the non-efficient way for now i suppose... thanks anyways :)

Comment: How is that non efficent?

Comment: Oh, because the only way i know how to do it otherwise is run the code on page_load. there's a good chance that the user won't enter that section of the page and then i just called a bunch of sql commands for no reason.

Comment: i don't know how to call non-static methods using javascript... that's probably the main reason to it.

Comment: You can add a scriptmanaget and mark your method with a pagemethod attribute and then you can call from js it will do a callback

Comment: You wont be able to access html but you send the data to the client and use js on client to modify html. Now i hate scriptmgr if rather use a webapi but start simple